# Question about transitivity with regards to big o notations

Tags: big-o

If f ∈ O(g) and g ∈ Θ(h) is f ∈ Θ(h)?

I would say yes, because: If the upper bounding of f is g, and g lies between two function `1/c*h` and `c*h`, then `c*h` must be an upper bounding for f also and consequently if `c*h` is an upper bounding for f and g then `1/c*h` must be a lower bounding for both. (The reciprocal value of a big number is very little).

Is this right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is not:

Imagine `f(x) = x, g(x) = 5*x^2 and h(x) = x^2`

`f ∈ O(g)` since `x^2` is an upper bound for `x`.

`g ∈ Θ(h)` since `x^2` is both and upper and lower bound for `x^2`.

but `f ∉ Θ(h)` since `x^2` is not a lower bound for `x`.

You are correct that `c*h(x)` is indeed an upper bound for `f(x)` but why do you believe `1/c*h(x)` must be a lower bound?

Comment: Okay, I understand'. My premise was that g must be the ideal upper bound of f (such that the highest exponents of both functions are equal). But n^2, or n^3, or 2^n could also be an upper bound for f since ... they grow actually faster than f. Thanks.